# trying to mouseover on a div to activate fadein of another div

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover, fadein, mouseout

I was trying to have a specific div fade in (left_panel_fade), and stay visible as long as the mouse is over the div called left_panel.

When I use this code, nothing happens when I mouseover the left_panel:

```
      $("#left_panel").mouseover(function() {$("#left_panel_hover").fadeIn("slow");});
      $("#left_panel").mouseout(function() {$("#left_panel_hover").fadeOut("slow");});
```

This code worked for me, but does not fade:

```
$("#left_panel").mouseover(function(){$("#left_panel_hover").css('visibility','visible'); });
$("#left_panel").mouseout(function() {$("#left_panel_hover").css('visibility','hidden'); });
```

why doesn't my first code work? am I using the fadeIn/fadeOut correctly?
i have tried changing mouseover and mouseout to mouseenter and mouseleave, with no results.

Comment: Where are the HTML and CSS..?

Comment: Is the `opacity` of `#left_panel_hover` set to `0` before trying to `fadeIn()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide `left_panel_hover` initially by using `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden`.

Notice that [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnaQz/) works fine, but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnaQz/1/) does nothing -- the only difference is how `left_panel_hover` is hidden in the CSS.

Comment: Thanks!! this worked perfectly. I changed visibility:hidden; to display:none; in the css and it completely fixed the problem. thanks again! I would upvote you, but i'm new so i have no rep.